# When try server side sorting with Grid.js it does multiple calls to the server that could be avoided

Tags: javascript, gridjs

I'm using Grid.js accessing server data and performing server side sorting (this on [Grid.js doc](https://gridjs.io/docs/examples/server-side-sort) ).

My problem is that when I try to sort a column it makes a number of calls to the server equal to the number of sortable columns.

Here's an example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uL6t8nd1/3/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/gridjs/dist/theme/mermaid.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gridjs/dist/gridjs.umd.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      new gridjs.Grid({
        columns: ['Title', 'Director', 'Producer'],
          sort: {
            multiColumn: false,
            server: {
              url: (prev, columns) => {
               if (!columns.length) return prev;
               const col = columns[0];
               const dir = col.direction === 1 ? 'asc' : 'desc';
               let colName = ['title', 'director', 'producer'][col.index];
               return `${prev}&order=${colName}&dir=${dir}`;
             }
            }
          },
                pagination: {
          limit: 3,
          server: {
            url: (prev, page, limit) => `${prev}?limit=${limit}&offset=${page * limit}`
          }
        },
        server: {
          url: 'https://swapi.dev/api/films?',
          then: data => data.results.map(m => [
            m.title, m.director, m.producer
          ]),
          total: data => data.count
        } 
      }).render(document.getElementById("wrapper"));

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to understand why it does it and how to avoid it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

It seems it's a know bug of the library.
Bug report : https://github.com/grid-js/gridjs/issues/1317
it's still not fixed(june 2023).

It's seems that this is the `sort` who make so much api calls

Comment: As of december 2023 and gridjs version 6.0.6 this problem still persist sadly. But it seems like they are aware and working on a fix for these problems. downgrading to 5.x helps but there are also some features missing. Seems like a pretty fundamental problem right now with this library.

Answer (score 0):

It's been fixed by the author, check the [issue tracked on GitHub](https://github.com/grid-js/gridjs/issues/1317#issuecomment-1891014945).
You can now just update it to the last version 6.1.0